# C char pointer and function argument passing

Tags: c, pointers

The two function getData and getData2 all can get right answers, are they valid?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 void getData(const char** data) {
     if(data == NULL) {
         printf("NULL\n");
     }
     *data = "error";
 }
 const char* getData2() {
     const char*p = "hello";
     return p;
 }
 int main(){
     const char *p = NULL;
     getData(&p);
     printf("data:%s\n",p);
     printf("data2:%s\n",getData2());
 }
```

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve? What do you mean by valid?

Comment: both contain bugs, `getData` writes to a null pointer, `getData2` should be using `const char*` rather than `char*`, any more comment depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This looks like C.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, `getData` does not write to a null pointer, the value the pointer points to is `nullptr`, but the pointer itself is not `nullptr`. `getData` should also be using `const char**` rather than `char**`.

Comment: @hellow   I mean If there is bugs in the code

Comment: @Ron yes, this is c code, not c++.

Comment: @Evgeny i fix the code.

Comment: @all, In the code above, for example, in the getData function, I want to return  some useful string msg to main. And I want to know, if the code fragment :*data = "error"; is ok, should I write like : *data = malloc(n), and use strcpy( *data,"error"); which one is valid

Comment: If you want to know, if there are bugs in the code, why don't you write it? If it is C code, why do you declare it as C++? Please be more careful and prepare a question on SO, because it is crucial for the first few moments somebody passes and hopefully answers your question. Afterwards it will not get much attention.

Comment: @Evgeny the way it is called it isn't writing to a null pointer but it has a check for whether the pointer itself is null, if this check fails it still writes to the null pointer

Answer (score 3):

```
char* p = "hello";
```

This is not allowed since C++11, but earlier versions allow it.

The string literal `"hello"` is stored in read-only memory that can't be modified, but a pointer to a non-const `char` has the ability to let the memory be modified, which will crash during runtime when pointing at a string literal.

A modern compiler won't accept such a conversion from `const char*` to `char*`.

Same with the `char** data` parameter and `*data = "error";` assignment. `data` should be type as `const char**` to make the assignment legal.

Comment: thanks for you correction, I has fix the bugs. And  I want to know, if the code fragment :*data = "error"; is ok, should I write like : *data = malloc(n), and use strcpy( *data,"error"); which one is valid

Comment: @darbe what do you mean by "valid"? The code is legal, whether it does what you want it to do depends on what you want it to do.

Comment: Both are valid, but in `*data = "error"`, you can't do anything like `(*data)[0] = 'E'`, because the memory stored "error" is read-only.  If you malloc a new space, then it will be modifiable. @darbe